# How to plot XGBClassifier as tree structure with the style of that givent by sklearn.tree.plot_tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

I was try use the following code to plot my XGBClssifier model for disliking the ploting style of that given by `xgboost.plot_tree`

```
from sklearn import tree
tree.plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

but got errors:

```
AttributeError: 'XGBClassifier' object has no attribute 'tree_'treetreetree
```

But I really want to plot trees as how it looks like in this tutorial:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-tree-plot-unveil-tree-structure-py

How can I achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

if you use xgboost, there is already a plot_tree function. so no need to use sklearn.

```
# plot decision tree
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from xgboost import plot_tree
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# fit model no training data
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)
# plot single tree

plot_tree(model)
plt.show()
```

plot_tree takes some parameters, For example, you can plot the 3th boosted tree in the sequence as follows:

```
plot_tree(model, num_trees=2)
```

or you can make it to be read left to right using

```
plot_tree(model, num_trees=0, rankdir='LR')
```